# Customize tags list for MissingTag rule

Tags: php, phpcodesniffer

I would like to use **PEAR.Commenting.FileComment.MissingTag** for my phpcs ruleset, but I need to customize the list of required tags.

Is it possible via some API or must I exclude this rule and write a new Sniff?

I was searching through documentation and CodeSniffer source files, but I didn't find any solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to customise the FileComment sniff, so you'd have to exclude that rule and write your own sniff if you want to customise the file commenting rules.

Extending the PEAR class might be a good way to get going, especially if you just want to change tags and tag orders.